# Fingerprint reader and ROS

Tags: ros, print

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
Is there a package or recommended tutorial for using a fingerprint reader with ROS?
I am actually planning to buy this model:
http://es.dhgate.com/usb-fingerprint-reader-password-lock-for/p-ff80808138bd3a540138d57a4f96511d.html

Any info or project example would be appreciated also!
Greetings ROS community.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56827/fingerprint-reader-and-ros/) by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 216 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of anyone using a fingerprint reader yet in ROS.  You will probably need to write a driver, and I suggest making a message to contain the fingerprint information to make communication and storage easier.

(Note: ROS does not use any authentication so it is not recommended for doing anything requiring security.)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-03**:
Many thanks tfoote. I will.